# List Reservations at all locations in the state of 'CA' - NEED SQL guidance

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM RESERVATION,HOTEL 
WHERE RESERVATION.GUESTID = HOTEL.HSTATE 
  AND HSTATE = 'CA';
```

I keep on trying this SQL command and I don't get anything. I think there might be something wrong with the foreign keys and all that. a little help please.

These are the tables

```
BRAND
GUEST
HOTEL
HTMLDB_PLAN_TABLE
RESERVATION
ROOM
ROOMTYPE
```

Comment: How do you expect anyone to tell you whether there is anything wrong with your query without knowing anything about what your database schema looks like? Although joining a guestid (which I assume refers to a Guest entity) with a hstate (which might be the State where the hotel is located) seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: And the actual **database** that you're using might be helpful, too. They all use SQL as their query language - but there are subtle nuances between MySQL, Postgres, IBM DB2, SQL Server, Oracle etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Still too little information. Table names aren't really enough. Please include columns (names and data types) and information on how the tables relate to each other.

Comment: i got it working, it was this:

SELECT * FROM RESERVATION, HOTEL
WHERE RESERVATION.HNUM=HOTEL.HNUM and HSTATE='CA';

Answer (score 2):

I'm just guessing here (from experience, and the fact that this seems like a homework assignment from any DB 101 course), but I would think that your Guest and Hotel tables are related via the Reservation table, and if that is correct, the query you're looking for would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Reservation
INNER JOIN Guest ON Reservation.GuestID = Guest.ID
INNER JOIN Hotel ON Reservation.HotelID = Hotel.ID
WHERE Hotel.HState = 'CA'
```

Adjust the column names to match your actual design (which you didn't inform us about).